# Reusing closed session in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I made my model and using `with` clause I used the same in a session:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

How can I use the above session `sess` since it is closed outside the with clause?

Comment: There is no way to reopen a session, and even if there was, it would be like starting a new session, because all the resources of the session (i.e. the state of the variables) are freed when it is closed. If you want to get back to a point where a closed session was before you need to checkpoint it before closing it and restore it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your model in the same `with` block:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(your_model, feed_dict={...})
```

Or create session and use it without `with`:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(your_model, feed_dict={...})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Taras. But what if I have already used it in with block and i want to use the same session after with block. Is there any way to do that if i haven't saved the session inside the with block.
Generally the error comes like "Attempted to use a closed session"

Comment: `with` block is used for temporary variables and they are destroyed at the block end, so session is destroyed. So you should use one of methods I've proposed.